# reading a binary file with mmap()

Tags: mmap

Could you please explain why my program reads strange values from a file? I'm trying to read a file using mmap. The reason I use this function is to understand how it works. Then I'd use it with /dev/mem in order to read binary data at specific physical memory address.

I made a file 'hello1.raw' using the following python script.

```
fd = open("hello1.raw", "w+b")
fd.write(b'01')

fd.close()
```

Then I tried to read it using the c program below.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){

int fd = open("hello1.raw",O_RDWR);

struct stat st;
fstat(fd, &st);
size_t size=st.st_size;

int * a = mmap(0, size, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC ,MAP_SHARED , fd, 0);
printf("address of hello1.raw: %p\n",a); 
printf("data in hello1.raw: %d\n", *a);

int b = munmap(a, size);
close(fd);

return 0;
}
```

But this program prints weird value.

```
address of hello.raw: 0x10238d000
data in hello.raw: 12592
```

The data is not 01 but 12592.

Comment: `d.write(b'01')` what is that supposed to mean? a character constant? `write()` expects three arguments, an int for the filedescriptor, a buffer (or pointer) for the data, and an int for the size. (Ok, it is python). Use od -CX or hexdump to see the actual contents. BTW: mmap() works on memory pages. You should assume nothing beyond the physical EOF.

Comment: @joop Thank you for your answer. So does it mean that the file hello1.raw I made doesn't contain binary value 01?

Comment: As I said: use hexdump or od -X to verify its contents. And use ls to verify its size and mode.

Comment: @SD11: You'd want to write `b'\x01'` to write the actual binary byte with value `1`. Also, not sure why you're opening the file for read & write, and mapping for read & execute; seems like opening and mapping for read is all you need.

Comment: BTW your python script writes the characters '0' and '1' to the file. hexdumping it results in 0x30 0x31. (and 12592 is 49 * 256 + 48)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){

int fd, rc , ii;
int *ptr;
struct stat st;
size_t size;

fd = open("hello1.raw", O_RDWR);

rc = fstat(fd, &st);
fprintf(stderr, "stat() = %d\n", rc);
size=st.st_size;
fprintf(stderr, "size=%zu\n", size);

ptr = mmap(0, size, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC ,MAP_SHARED , fd, 0);
fprintf(stderr, "address of hello1.raw: %p\n", ptr);

for (ii=0; ii < size/sizeof *ptr; ii++) {
   printf("data in raw[%d]: %d\n", ii, ptr[ii]);
        }

rc = munmap(ptr, size);
fprintf(stderr, "unmap() = %d\n", rc);
close(fd);

return 0;
}
```

---

- First of all: check the return values for system calls and report to stderr.
- Second: mmap() works with pages. if st.st_size is not a multiple of the page size it is rounded up. (Linux fills the rest with zeros)
- Test this by putting "OMG\n" into the hello1.raw file (4 bytes) and run the program.
- now remove one character )eg -->> "OM\n") end rerun the program.

---

RESULT 1:

```
$ ./a.out
stat() = 0
size=4
address of hello1.raw: 0xa64000
data in raw[0]: 172445007
unmap() = 0
```

RESULT 2:

```
$ ./a.out
stat() = 0
size=3
address of hello1.raw: 0xe37000
unmap() = 0
```

---

Explanation: in the first run the file has size=4, the mmap succeeds, and the int is printed. (sizeof int is 4).
In the second case, mmap succeeds, but the int is not printed (my version of the loop refuses to reference mmapped memory beyond the eof) if you *would* allow references beyond eof the upper bytes(assuming Big endian here) of the int value would show as zero, because the system has zero padded the page.

if you want to see the effect of the nul-padding, change the for-loop to `for (ii=0; ii <= size/sizeof *ptr; ii++) {` and repeat the above experiment.